# NovaClient - create cloud server using "boot" - ERROR (BadRequest): Multiple possible networks found

Tags: cloud, openstack, novaclient

I'm a fresher to OpenStack and NovaClient API.
NovaClient version: 2.20.0

I have successfully logged in to my OpenStack account and have NovaClient API privileges.

I was trying to create a cloud server on OpenStack using nova client with "boot" command as follows.

```
nova boot --flavor 2 --image 004337db-0dad-4c14-a154-726a1428f524 ubuntu-1204
```

I'm unable to complete the request since getting following error.

```
ERROR (BadRequest): Multiple possible networks found, use a Network ID to be more specific. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-25e05d24-b152-481c-aaa3-de563ca28cfa)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Please provide a direction to proceed from here.

Link I'm referring is as follows.

[1] http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/useful-python-novaclient-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.
Since I have multiple networks in OpenStack cloud, OpenStack doesn't seem to assign a default network to my server upon boot if I don't specify any network during creation.

I did use `--nic net-id=<private-net-id>` switch and server boot was successful.

```
nova boot ubuntu-12.04 --flavor 2 --image 004337db-0dad-4c14-a154-726a1428f524 --nic net-id=b55f009a-1cc6-4b17-924f-4ae0ee18db5e
```